# Can I use class with variable parameter in PostCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, postcss

can I use class in [PostCss](https://github.com/postcss) with variable parameter ?

Something like this:

`.my-class(varWidth) { width: varWidth }`

And than use this class in React component:

`import {myClass} import './MyComponent.scss'`

`...`

`<div className={myClass(100px)}></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use PostCSS Loader for this (Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS).
Install PostCSS Loader by:

```
npm i -D postcss-loader
```

Configuration
postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
parser: 'sugarss',
plugins: {
'postcss-import': {},
'postcss-cssnext': {},
'cssnano': {}
 }
}
```

You can read more about common PostCSS Config here.https://github.com/michael-ciniawsky/postcss-load-config

Comment: Thank you. Actually I install PostCSS  normally and it work correctly. I don't know does this library has the tool for decide my problem (at this time I don't find this ability). Particularly use class as function with variable parameter.